# 404 JSP file not found Dynamic Web Module imported project

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I imported a project from sample codes from a book https://github.com/pauldeck/springmvc-2ed/tree/master/chapter-02/eclipse/appdesign1 into Eclipse.

I convert the project to Dynamic Web Module by right click project>properties>project facets>convert to facets form. However, when I run as run on server on Tomcat 8.5, I got HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArKnW.png)

Why my controller is already working but I cannot find the resource jsp in my webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Tomcat server returns message JSP is not found, the url is successfully dispatched by the controller. Have you checked if your jsp files are deployed when run on server?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0t8l.png)

make sure you have included all your resources under deployment assembly configuration.